# Origen de "mano" para denotar primero

Tags: modismos, méxico

Una expresión común en México es `¡pido mano!` que quiere decir `quiero ser el primero`. De hecho, yo llegué a escuchar `cutimano` e incluso `anticutimano` para añadir énfasis.
¿De donde vienen estas tres expresiones?

Comment: En los juegos, se le dice `mano` al que juega primero y `pie` al que juega último. De ahí proviene la expresión mexicana. Supongo que lo que preguntás es el origen de la expresión original, ¿no?

Comment: @angus Iba a comentar lo mismo, pero específicamente para el juego de cartas "Mus" al que se juega mucho en España. No sabía que ese término se usa en otros juegos también.

Comment: @neizan: esa puede ser la explicacion. Aun resta saber de donde vienen los otros dos terminos mas raros...

Comment: En el Río de la Plata, en el juego del Truco también se usa mano y pie con el mismo significado.que comenta @angus.

Answer (score 5):

Adivino que proviene de los juegos de naipes en los que los jugadores se sientan en círculo, y el que empieza a jugar es quien está al costado de quien reparte las cartas... lo que se expresa diciendo que está "a la mano" (izquierda o derecha) del jugador que reparte. Así, "estar a la mano (izquierda o derecha)" pasó a expresarse "ser mano", lo cual a su vez pasó a significar "ser el primero en jugar", o más en general, "mano = primero".

Comment: Coincido. En España no se utiliza "ser mano" excepto en juegos de cartas, donde efectivamente hace referencia al primero en jugar en cada ronda (también llamada "mano").

Answer (score 5):

Yo soy la más chica de 7 hermanos y de ellos aprendí esto para ser el primero en algún juego o en algún evento familiar (lo aplicábamos para todo), y según sé es:
**Mano**, **Cutimano**, **Anticutimano**, **Anticutimano Coronita de Dios** (y ahí sí no hay quien te gane)